# check if a string can be converted to double using strtod

Tags: c++

I need to check if a string could be converted to a double, the string could be

`"36"`,`"36.5C"`(I don't want this one to be a double), etc.

If I use the code below, it can identify `"36.5C"` is a string which is what I want, but it can not identify that`"36"` is a double. If I delete `"pEnd!=NULL"` in the `if` statement then the function can not identify that`"36.5C"` is a string.

```
string word="36.5C";
const char* c=word.c_str();
char * pEnd=NULL;
double d=strtod(c, &pEnd);

if((d==0 && pEnd==c) || pEnd!=NULL) 
{
   //to see whether the word is a string
}
```

Comment: Are you using C++11? Then check out `std::stod`. It will throw an exception when `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion can take place. Otherwise you need to use `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Beware of corner cases when you specify. In you case, what do you want to do with "36.0  " or "36.0\r", that is when there are blank characters after the double. And once you are thinkink about that, what about  "36.12  12.36"  ?

Answer (score 3):

strtod will set pEnd to point to the first char after the chars that took part in calculating the double.

With input "36.5C" you actually have:

'3','6','.','5','C','\0'

where '\0' represents the string termination.

So strtod will give you d=36.5 and pEnd will point to the 'C'.

So your if-statement will give true due to the pEnd!=NULL

With input "36" you actually have:

'3','6','\0'

So strtod will give you d=36.0 and pEnd will **point** to the '\0', i.e. the first character after those used for the double.

So your if-statement will again give true due to pEnd!=NULL because pEnd points to the '\0' but pEnd itself is not NULL.

Maybe you want

```
*pEnd!='\0'   // note the *
```

in the if-statement instead to check whether all characters were used for the conversion.

Comment: The name "NULL" usually means the null pointer, not the character with value zero (called "NUL" in ASCII). It's very confusing to use it for something other than a pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo, thanks for your answer,I think I need to use *pEnd==0

Comment: by the way, I think it just need to use *pEnd!=0 to identify strings that can not be converted to double? I saw someone use if(d==0 && pEnd==c)

Comment: @lxdthriller - the first part of the if-statement takes care of the empty string. If you want an empty string as a double with value 0.0 then you shall <b>not</b> have that part of the if. However, if you want an empty string as a string instead of double, you'll need it.

Comment: @molbdnilo - Thanks. Yes, it was confusing with the NULL as string termination. Instead I've changed it to '\0'.

Comment: @StillLearning Good stuff.